# como se crea una funcion en PL/PgSQL

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, funciones, plpgsql

hola estoy creando una función en PL/PgSQL el tema es que tengo algunos problemas y dudas por que no conozco mucho la sintaxis.

Estoy mandando dos parámetros, un nombre de una categoría y la url de esta, pretendo realizar un select a la tabla con lo que mando, luego en la estructura del case pregunto si las url son las mismas. De ser diferentes solo se realiza un update a la tabla y en el otro caso si es null se realiza un insert.

Eso es todo, aunque también me gustaría poner un return mas entendible, quizás poder retornar la tabla completa, esto es lo que tengo... hasta el momento me tira un error en la línea del end. seria de mucha ayuda si alguien me pudiera corregir los errores ya que estoy  aprendiendo gracias.

```
    Create or replace function pi(nomcat character varying(30),urlcat character varying(30))
    returns int 
    as
    $$
    Begin
    select categorie_id as idd, name_categorie as nc, url_categorie as uc where nc = nomcat;
    CASE WHEN uc != urlcat THEN UPDATE categories
                           SET url_categorie = urlcat,
                           createdat = now();
    CASE WHEN idd = null THEN Insert into categories(name_categorie,url_categorie,createdat) 
    values (nomcat,urlcat,now())
            END;

    Return 1;

    $$

    Language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade el error puntual que obtienes actualmente. Idealmente, ayudaría que indicaras con qué datos estás probando para que otros puedan replicar tu problema

Answer (score 0):

El procedimiento que tu quieres sería algo así:

Esta función busca una categoría por nombre, si la encuentra y la url no coincide con la que se pasa como parámetro, actualiza la misma, sino la encuentra la inserta. Retorna la tabla categories.

Tené en cuenta que va a funcionar siempre y cuando el nombre de la categoría (name_categorie) sea único, caso contrario el primer select devolvería mas de una fila y tendrías que guardar dicho resultado en un cursor y recorrelo para actualizar todas las categorías con el mismo nombre.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pi(nomcat character varying(30), urlcat character varying(30))
RETURNS TABLE (categorie_id INTEGER, name_categorie character varying(30), url_categorie character varying(30),  createdat TIMESTAMP) LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $$

DECLARE
    idd integer;
    uc character varying(30);

BEGIN
    
    SELECT c.categorie_id, c.url_categorie INTO idd, uc
    FROM categories c
    WHERE c.name_categorie = nomcat;
    
    IF (idd IS NULL) THEN
        INSERT INTO categories (name_categorie, url_categorie, createdat) 
        VALUES (nomcat, urlcat, now());     
    ELSE
        IF uc != urlcat THEN 
            UPDATE categories c
            SET url_categorie = urlcat,
                createdat = now()
            WHERE c.name_categorie = nomcat;
        END IF; 
    END IF;

    RETURN QUERY SELECT c.categorie_id, c.name_categorie, c.url_categorie, c.createdat FROM categories AS c ORDER BY c.categorie_id;

END

$$;
```

Para llamar a la función:

```
SELECT * FROM pi('xxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');
```